# why this wrong in robot.txt file even after specifing URL?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console, googlebot

In robot.txt file I have put a URL `/custompages/*` and google bot should not crawl the pages which are matched with "/custompages/".

But when I looked into webmaster, I can still see the error messages from those links.

```
User-agent: *        
Disallow: /search/application/*
Disallow: /custompages/*
```

above is my robot.txt file.

On webmaster I can see `Googlebot couldn't access the contents of this URL because the server had an internal error when trying to process the request. These errors tend to be with the server itself, not with the request.`
for the URL

`custompages/savesearch?alid=9161`

Where wrong might have happened..?

Answer (score 0):

```
Disallow: /search/application/
Disallow: /custompages/
```

Is enough, the * sign is not needed.